# Get current working directory

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

How can I get the path to an actively running vbscript/classic ASP page? I have used several code snippets,  but all are giving the current working directory (C drive path) but I need to get current file path where the script is located.

I am trying to display this in both a `.VBS` file and an `.ASP` file.

```
Dim folderName1
folderName1 = ""

Dim fso1
Set fso1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Dim fullpath
fullpath = fso1.GetAbsolutePathName(folderName1)

response.write("folder spec: " & folderName1)
response.write( "fullpath:    " & fullpath)
```

above code is giving C path.

Comment: Hi - It is not 100% clear what you are asking here.... In your script example (assuming Classic ASP Vbscript?) Fullpath should be returning the current working directory, but you go on to say that the code is giving C drive path, but you need the current file path...? Can you please update and give a more detailed example of what you are asking because I don't understand what you are missing. Are you wanting the output to show the location of where the asp/vbs file is located?

Comment: Lets suppose I am running abc.vbs file. I need to get its full path where abc.vbs file is stored.

Comment: If you are running abc.vbs - you would not be using response.write as you have written here, you would be using wscript.echo - response.write  is a directive you would use in Classic ASP...? This can make a difference to what you are after here.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using the Windows Scripting Host, `WScript.ScriptFullName` returns the full path of the script that is currently executing. You can truncate that string to determine the folder.

```
strFolder = Left(WScript.ScriptFullName, InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullName, "\"))
```

If you have a `FileSystemObject` (or don't mind creating one), you can also use the `GetParentFolderName` method:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in your comment:

Let's suppose I am running abc.vbs file. I need to get its full path where abc.vbs is stored

We are going to assume you're talking about finding the path where the script is stored:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
wscript.Echo fso.GetParentFolderName(wscript.ScriptFullName)
```

The example you have provided will not work in a .vbs file - you have used `response.write` which is not a valid directive in a `.vbs` file.

If you are trying to get the current directory of a running "script", in a classic ASP page using vbscript, you could use:

```
response.write(Server.MapPath("."))
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It is throwing Error

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: 'fso'

Comment: You mentioned "abc.vbs" - are you sure you are not running "abc.asp"? :)

Comment: I am testing from both side. using .asp and .vbs both

Comment: and you get the 800a01a8 when running in the .vbs file?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include the way you could achieve this in classic asp (vbscript):  response.write(Server.MapPath("."))

Answer (score 0):

You can use server.variables. The script to view all server.variables.

```
<%
dim item
for each item in Request.ServerVariables
  Response.Write(item & "= "&Request.ServerVariables(item) & "<br>")
next
%>
```

Then you can use string operation for example "split" to define the folder or other.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the entire ServerVariables, you can just the the following simple line of code.  It also does not require WScript.

```
parentFolder = Request.ServerVariables("APPL_PHYSICAL_PATH")
```

Comment: This does not work from an include or `Server.Execute(...)` file.